# NextJS. How to rebuild page each day once at some specified time using getStaticProps function?

Tags: next.js

I'm using NextJS getServerSideProps to get data from back-end. Back-end data that I need for current page changes each day once at 4UTC. I want to implement getStaticProps which will rebuild all pages once each day, because data on server changes only once each day.
I know about revalidate, but making revalidate with 24 hours also revalidates after each request. Also revalidating 24 hours is not exactly at 4UTC. So, how to rebuild page each day once at some specified time using getStaticProps function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use On-demand Revalidation. Starting with v12.1.0, Next.js supports on-demand Incremental Static Regeneration to manually purge the Next.js cache for a specific page. This makes it easier to update your site when:

```
Content from your headless CMS is created or updated
Ecommerce metadata changes (price, description, category, reviews, etc.)
or for your case, at 4am everyday data is updated.
```

Inside `getStaticProps`, you do not need to specify `revalidate` to use on-demand revalidation. If `revalidate` is omitted, Next.js will use the default value of `false` (no revalidation) and only revalidate the page on-demand when `unstable_revalidate` is called.

Link for reference- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

Answer (score 0):

Just hint, never tested ... There is a discussion about [the cache purging on Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22384). In your case it should be combination of cron job and calling of purge.